# Arduino one button On/Off control

Tags: button, arduino

I'm trying to find a way to use one button to enable/disable commands. (actually, it's a multicolor LED i'm trying to start/stop changing colors)

My code is under here, but it does not work, if anyone could tell me what's wrong, i can't see it...

```
int red = 0;
int redPin = 9;
int blue = 0;
int bluePin = 11;
int green = 0;
int greenPin = 10;
int state = 0;
int stateModulo = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
}


void checkButton(int var, int result) {
  if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
      var++;
      result = var%2;
    }
}

void changecolor(int startColor,int endColor,int startPin,int endPin,int delayTime)
{
  for (endColor = 0; endColor <= 255; endColor++)
  {
     checkButton(state,stateModulo);
     if (stateModulo == 0) {
       startColor = 255 - endColor;
       analogWrite(endPin, endColor);
       analogWrite(startPin, startColor);
       delay(delayTime);
     }
  }
}

void loop() {
   changecolor(red,green,redPin,greenPin,10);
   changecolor(green,blue,greenPin,bluePin,10);
   changecolor(blue,red,bluePin,redPin,10);
 }
```

Comment: You're not changing `stateModulo` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below, `result` is not passed by reference, nor returned.
The same applies to `var`, after you have modified it you throw away any edit you have made.

```
void checkButton(int var, int result) {
  if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
      var++;
      result = var%2;
    }
}
```

I can recommend you a good C++ book where to learn some language basics.
My suggestion: Thinking in C++, by Bruce Eckel.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
//Buttons

int button1 = 7;
int button2 = 6;
int button3 = 4;
int button4 = 2;


//Relays
int rl1 = 13;
int rl2 = 12;
int rl3 = 11;
int rl4 = 8;


//States for Relay and Button (1)

int state1 = HIGH;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading1;           // the current reading from the input pin
int previous1 = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin

//States for Relay and Button (2)

int state2 = HIGH;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading2;           // the current reading from the input pin
int previous2 = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin

//States for Relay and Button (3)

int state3 = HIGH;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading3;           // the current reading from the input pin
int previous3 = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin

//States for Relay and Button (4)

int state4 = HIGH;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading4;           // the current reading from the input pin
int previous4 = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin




// the follow variables are long's because the time, measured in miliseconds,
// will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
long time1 = 0;          // the last time the output pin was toggled
long time2 = 0;
long time3 = 0;
long time4 = 0;

long debounce1 = 200;   // the debounce time, increase if the output flickers
long debounce2 = 200;
long debounce3 = 200;
long debounce4 = 200;


void setup()
{
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  pinMode(button3, INPUT);
  pinMode(button4, INPUT);

  pinMode(rl1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rl2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rl3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rl4, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  reading1 = digitalRead(button1);
  reading2 = digitalRead(button2);
  reading3 = digitalRead(button3);
  reading4 = digitalRead(button4);


  // if the input just went from LOW and HIGH and we've waited long enough
  // to ignore any noise on the circuit, toggle the output pin and remember
  // the time
  //Condition Relay 1
  if (reading1 == HIGH && previous1 == LOW && millis() - time1 > debounce1) {
    if (state1 == HIGH)
      state1 = LOW;
    else
      state1 = HIGH;

    time1 = millis();    
  }

  //Condition Relay 2
    if (reading2 == HIGH && previous2 == LOW && millis() - time2 > debounce2) {
    if (state2 == HIGH)
      state2 = LOW;
    else
      state2 = HIGH;

    time2 = millis();    
  }

  //Condition Relay 3
    if (reading3 == HIGH && previous3 == LOW && millis() - time3 > debounce3) {
    if (state3 == HIGH)
      state3 = LOW;
    else
      state3 = HIGH;

    time3 = millis();    
  }

  //Condition Relay 4
    if (reading4 == HIGH && previous4 == LOW && millis() - time4 > debounce4) {
    if (state4 == HIGH)
      state4 = LOW;
    else
      state4 = HIGH;

    time4 = millis();    
  }




  digitalWrite(rl1, state1);
  digitalWrite(rl2, state2);
  digitalWrite(rl3, state3);
  digitalWrite(rl4, state4);


  previous1 = reading1;
  previous2 = reading2;
  previous3 = reading3;
  previous4 = reading4;
}
```